# How to get all form fields in a winforms app as one parameter?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm building a new WinForms application, and I've got a user control form that has about 20 form fields on it.

In my web version of this form, I just push all those fields in through a formCollection, but I don't know if there's something similar in windows forms (I'm sorta new to winforms).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a method like so:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var formFields = **formFieldCollection**;

    var firstName = formFields.FirstName.Text;
    var lastName = formFields.LastName.Text;
}
```

Is something like that possible? Does something like that exist?

Comment: It really would help if you explained [what you're trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), not just what you're doing, because what you are doing makes no sense. All form fields are available to all event handlers directly; you don't need to “push” anything, either through collections or parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to access the fields on your user control from within the form directly. This isn't best practice, but if you really want to do it, here is a potential way:

There is no need to build up a field collection. With a bit of modification you can access the fields directly.

By default when you create a user control, all the controls (fields etc) that you drop on it are marked as private and cannot therefore be accessed outside of the user control.
Using the properites (right click the field and select properties) you can change the Modifer from private to public. You will then be able to access the fields from outside the control.

For example, if I had a user control called MyUserControl with a field on called FirstName and LastName, I could do the following:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var formFields = **formFieldCollection**;

    var firstName = MyUserControl.FirstName.Text;
    var lastName = MyUserControl.LastName.Text;
}
```

Like I said, this isn't recommended at all. Part of the point of a user control is to wrap up a set of fields / functionality in a separate entity and only expose the properties and functionality you need using a defined public interface.

Comment: I don't want to access them from outside the user control. I want to access them in the user control's code-behind.

Comment: Then just do var firstName = FirstName.Text

Comment: So it operates pretty much the way old ASP.Net did, with direct access to all scoped controls?

Answer (score 1):

Each control in a Windows Form has a Name property. Inside the Code-Behind-File (the one where your event handler sits) you can access them directly. Let's assume you have 2 textboxes which are named `txtFirstname` and `txtLastname` (which you can prove in the designer):

[image: Designer and Document Outline Window]

Your code would look like this then:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    var firstName = txtFirstname.Text;
    var lastName = txtLastname.Text;
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can do this by using the `Controls` property of the form -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get all controls
    var formControls = this.Controls;

    //then get your control with their name as key 
    var button1 = formControls["button1"];
    var firstName = formControls["firstName"];
}
```

You can read more here -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]

Comment: Why would you do that rather than just reference the control by name? You are building a dependency on the control name that if the control name changes will still compile but will fail at runtime

Comment: @SimonClough I will be glad if you provide a solution without name dependencies for windows forms. BTW, why the name will be changed?